# Is there a low level website blocker for OSX?

Tags: macos, big-sur, websites

I'm looking for a very low level website blocker for MacOS.

Let's say that I want to block Twitter. I want to block it in a way that **I can't unblock it without reinstalling the operating system.**

**I'm aware of software such as:
https://heyfocus.com/ or browser extensions or changing the DNS or host file. But these are too easy to disable. Also Screen Time by Apple doesn't work.**

I want to block distracting websites from ever working on my Macbook. Does something like this exist? Or if not, is it possible to create something like this?

Comment: „I can't unblock it without reinstalling the operating system.“ is basically impossible to achieve as long as you want to retain the ability to do other admin-level stuff.

Comment: Hmm, so the solution would involve gaining admin rights and throwing away the password in some form or another. I remember Windows had something similar where the program would install a hidden driver. But I can imagine this is more difficult on OSX.